# Get registered emails accounts

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have an Android app that should be used for some of the company personnel only and I was thinking to prevent any one else to use the app is to get registered emails accounts in the device and compare if they are exists in online database, I need only to know how to get current registered emails accounts from any device using Firemonkey ?

This approach will work even if the employee changed his/her mobile device but I am open to other suggestions.

I use Delphi XE 8

Comment: Why not just implement your own user registration and authentication?

Comment: @JerryDodge because I did not think of that :) I am going to do it, thanks

Comment: "Personals" — do you mean personnel? Personals are classified advertisements for relationships.

Comment: Find Complete tutorial from here : http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/getregistered-email-account-from-device_96

Comment: @Kishan thanks, but I dont know how to call AccountManager from Delphi

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple:

Add this permission to manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

And then request the google accounts like this:

```java
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
for (Account account : accounts) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Found: " + account.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gero, I am using Delphi, should I add a unit to uses clause to use AccountManager ?

Comment: Sorry @Wel, never used delpi, but found this documentation about adding uses-permission http://delphi.org/2013/10/delphi-xe5-android-uses-permissions/

Comment: no problem, I found that AccountManager is not defined in Delphi

Comment: See this detailed answer to a similar SO question on http://stackoverflow.com/a/39581114/2817399 that resolves the question for Delphi developers