# How to fire notification using TimeEdit

Tags: android, notifications, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

im trying to fire a notification in specific time using TimeEdit, it didnt work!
the code i used..

```
try
MyNot.Name := Edit1.Text;
MyNot.AlertBody := Edit2.Text;
MyNot.FireDate := Now + TimeEdit1.Time;
NotificationCenter1.ScheduleNotification(MyNot);
Finally
MyNot.DisposeOf;
```

im using Delphi10 Seattle Update1.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Notifications#Creating_Notifications

Comment: nothing about TimeEdit buddy @kami

Comment: Don't think about TTimeEdit. I think, your problem not in this control. Try to use `myNot.FireDate:=IncSecond(Now, 30);` for example

Comment: it works using InSecond, but i cant fire notification using the TimeEdit! @kami

Comment: What value you pass to TimeEdit?

Comment: `MyNot.FireDate := Now + TimeEdit1.Time;`  @kami

Comment: I see this. I mean value inside `TimeEdit1`. Something like `00:05:00`. Value, that user enter into this control.

Comment: @kami: And what is that supposed to represent to your app exactly? `TTimeEdit` represents an absolute time of day. You are adding that to the current clock timestamp. So, do you want the notification to fire 5 minutes after the current date/time, or do you want it to fire at exactly 12:05am of the current date? Those are two completely different things. So what are you really trying to accomplish? If you want to fire at a *specific* time of a *specific* date, look at functions like `EncodeDateTime()`, `ReplaceTime()`, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is not my app :) I also think that OP want enter absolute time, but this code works with relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Now()` returns a `TDateTime` that represents the current clock date/time.  You are then adding the user's entered time relative to the current date/time.  For example, if the user enters `00:05:00`, you will be adding 5 minutes to the current date/time.

If you want the notification to fire at a *specific* time of the current date, use the `Date()` function instead of the `Now()` function so that you are adding the entered time relative to midnight (`00:00:00am`):

```
MyNot.FireDate := Date + TimeEdit1.Time;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `SysUtils.ReplaceTime()` function instead:

```
var
  dt: TDateTime;

dt := Date;
ReplaceTime(dt, TimeEdit1.Time);
MyNot.FireDate := dt;
```

This has the additional benefit that you can then configure whatever date you want, such as from the `SysUtils.EncodeDate()` function:

```
var
  wYear, wMonth, wDay: Word;
  dt: TDateTime;

wYear := ...;
wMonth := ...;
wDay := ...;
dt := EncodeDate(wYear, wMonth, wDay) + TimeEdit1.Time;
MyNot.FireDate := dt;
```

Or:

```
var
  wYear, wMonth, wDay: Word;
  dt: TDateTime;

wYear := ...;
wMonth := ...;
wDay := ...;
dt := EncodeDate(wYear, wMonth, wDay);
ReplaceTime(dt, TimeEdit1.Time);
MyNot.FireDate := dt;
```

Comment: Many Thanks mate,Perfect. Please can You check my other post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963244/how-to-get-device-email-address-in-delphi-10], Thanks again