# Getting device Email address in android using Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10 seattle for developing android mobile application and I have the requirement to get the device email Id. For that I have tried to use the following example [for getting EMail address of Mobile.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963244/how-to-get-device-email-address-in-delphi-10) But when I tried to interfaces (JAccountClass, JAccount, JAccountManagerClass) it is asking some other interfaces - JActivity, JAccountManagerCallback and JAccountManagerFuture . Please help me to find these dependency classes. And where can I get these files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the [android-object-pascal-wrapper](https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper) repository. (Check these [android.accounts.AccountManager](https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper/blob/5f21605bd45a1947f8de2cf37c2f2c5ee239197a/android-23/android.accounts.AccountManager.pas), [android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture](https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper/blob/5f21605bd45a1947f8de2cf37c2f2c5ee239197a/android-23/android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture.pas)   )

Comment: I have added the above files and then while compiling I'm getting error that file not found - android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture,  android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback, android.app.Activity, android.content.ClipData. So if I add these files, then it is asking more dependency files and if I set the search path of as folder , then also I'm getting some circular error message.  Please help to solve this dependency issue.

Comment: Any idea how to compile this unit

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the vagaries and peccadilloes of the code in that repository here is a unit that works in Delphi 10 Seattle.

Note that a specified account type can have multiple accounts registered, which is why this code returns an array of them.

```
unit AccountEmailsU;

interface

function GetAccountEmails(const AccountType: String): TArray<String>;

implementation

uses
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.Jni,
{$IF Declared(RTLVersion) and (RTLVersion >= 31)}
  // Delphi 10.1 Berlin adds in full imports for the accounts classes
  Androidapi.JNI.Accounts;
{$ELSE}
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os;

type
// ===== Forward declarations =====

  JAccount = interface;//android.accounts.Account
  JAccountManager = interface;//android.accounts.AccountManager

// ===== Interface declarations =====

  JAccountClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{94EE6861-F326-489F-8919-E20B39E3D9C1}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/accounts/Account')]
  JAccount = interface(JObject)
    ['{71476381-8B6E-471F-9189-9857ECD7508C}']
    function _Getname: JString; cdecl;
    function _Gettype: JString; cdecl;
    property name: JString read _Getname;
    property &type: JString read _Gettype;
  end;
  TJAccount = class(TJavaGenericImport<JAccountClass, JAccount>) end;

  JAccountManagerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{96273844-2D84-47F0-BFD5-14B73402F843}']
    {class} function &get(context: JContext): JAccountManager; cdecl;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/accounts/AccountManager')]
  JAccountManager = interface(JObject)
    ['{9FA4077B-4628-433C-BAFC-9EB299DA9C98}']
    function getAccountsByType(type_: JString): TJavaObjectArray<JAccount>; cdecl;
  end;
  TJAccountManager = class(TJavaGenericImport<JAccountManagerClass, JAccountManager>) end;
{$ENDIF}

function GetAccountEmails(const AccountType: String): TArray<String>;
var
  AccountManager: JAccountManager;
  Accounts: TJavaObjectArray<JAccount>;
  Account: JAccount;
  AccountLoopCounter: Integer;
begin
{$IF RTLVersion >= 30}
  AccountManager := TJAccountManager.JavaClass.get(TAndroidHelper.Context);
{$ELSE}
  AccountManager := TJAccountManager.JavaClass.get(SharedActivityContext);
{$ENDIF}
  if AccountManager <> nil then
  begin
    Accounts := AccountManager.getAccountsByType(StringToJString(AccountType));
    if Accounts <> nil then
    begin
      SetLength(Result, Accounts.Length);
      for AccountLoopCounter := 0 to Pred(Accounts.Length) do
      begin
        //Account := Accounts.Items[AccountLoopCounter];
        Account := TJAccount.Wrap(Accounts.GetRawItem(AccountLoopCounter));
        Result[AccountLoopCounter] := JStringtoString(Account.name);
      end
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure RegisterTypes;
begin
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('AccountEmailsU.JAccount', TypeInfo(AccountEmailsU.JAccount));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('AccountEmailsU.JAccountManager', TypeInfo(AccountEmailsU.JAccountManager));
end;

initialization
  RegisterTypes;
end.
```

Comment: Note the usage examples in the extended answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39581114/2817399 - the note to ensure you have the right permission is important.

Comment: After implementing the Android 26, getAccountsByType does not return any values.. How can I able to retrieve the Emails

Comment: I'll see if I can run a test on a device over the next day or two. In the mean time, I'd request that if you deem the answer above to have answered your question back in 2017, you mark it as such.